# can't generate component in angular6.1.1 with properties inline-template and inline-styles

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have installed Angular6 on Ubuntu-18 machine,

I created project by `ng new project --routing`,

then I wanted to generate components and with inline-styles and inline-templates,

my command was `ng g c microsoftroute -it -is`,

but it gave error in terminal as,

```
ng g c microsoftroute -it -is
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"inlineStyle":true,"inlineTemplate":true,"i":[true,true],"changeDetection":"Default","styleext":"css","spec":true,"flat":false,"skipImport":false,"export":false,"entryComponent":false}
    Errors:

  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(i).
```

before this I am using latest version of anular6,
my output of `ng -v` is as

```
ng -v
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|                |___/

Angular CLI: 6.1.1
Node: 8.11.3OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.0... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.1
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.1
@angular/cli                      6.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.1
@schematics/angular               0.7.1
@schematics/update                0.7.1
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Comment: try with latest version of nodejs

Comment: @Arash, I updated to node, but same problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using alias names as flags `-it -is`, but in latest angular6, unlike previous, they have been changed to `-t` for `--inline-template` and `-s` for `--inline-style`,

[angular-generate-component documentation for reference](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component) [image]

Comment: actually, I was following tutorial of previous Angular version. Documentation helped indeed.